# MYSQL: Should I create indexes on large tables used as logs?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a basic analytics mysql database table which keeps track of all ipaddresses and urls visited on a user's visit and the time they visited. 
There are a large number of inserts (millions per day).

After a few days, running a query on the table to try to find out how many users visited on a particular day takes a very long time.

Should I add an index to the table? Will it recreate the index after every insert, and is it worth it?

Or is there a better way to speed up my analytics queries?

This is probably a common situation (everyone has logs). What is the best way to maintain this table?

Comment: How frequently do you use that table? Is it only for an incidental ad hoc query or do you want constant updates on running total of the nr of visitors? Is it only nr of visitors on a day or do you also run other queries? What amount of history do you need (e.g. a week, a month, a year)?

Comment: @Martin: Currently, I use the tables to check a few times per day the number of visitors who visited that day and the past X number of days.  Max number of days I normally check are the past two weeks or so. I don't need a longer history than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MYSQL 5.0 introdcue [Archive Storage Engine](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/storage-engine.html),
I believe that answer most your question

Should I add an index to the table
- yes, if your want to perform search

Will it recreate the index after every insert
- is handle internally by mysql

worth it
- depends, adding index will slow-down database write operation a bit (depending how many index and record length)

Or is there a better way to speed up my analytic queries
- if you just want to perform simple calculation, you can consider split the data daily (each table to hold a logging for each day). Or you can prepare some sort of query cache warm-up script

Comment: thanks for the answers. I'm basically worried about if there is a large performance hit if I add an index. Do you know in general if indexes slow down inserts significantly, or how I can check how much time it takes?

Comment: @eric - Depends on your design. You can create a daily log table without any index, and insert the data back into the consolidate table (with index) after day end. As suggested by other users, INSERT delayed is a good choice too

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. from what i read, INSERT delayed just delays the query until no other queries are being run. is there also a performance boost for INSERT delayed?

Comment: @eric - The idea for insert delayed is for less crucial data. Is perfect for logging. Actually I have done a project exactly what you did. BUT we log the request via apache log, and run a daily cronjob to process the log, and pump it back to database for further usage in hadoop - http://hadoop.apache.org/

Answer (score 3):

Any table that will later be queried should use indexes.  Look at INSERT DELAYED which returns quickly and is designed for logging:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-delayed.html

This is probably the best option for log tables, although you could also look at the Archive storage engine, but that is more concerned with space than lookups:-

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/archive-storage-engine.html

Comment: thanks for the reference to insert delayed. Do you know if Archive is faster than MyISAM for select queries in general?

Comment: I don't know definitively, but I would expect that MyISAM is faster for querying.  I believe that the Archive engine compresses the data which has to be expanded on query.

Answer (score 1):

It will not recreate it but it will update the index. Yes, that takes some time, though not much more than a simple table update.

Anyway, if you are going to select from the tables with WHERE, you have no other choice than to create an index, otherwise those selects will be painfully slow.

Comment: thanks for the answers. I'm basically worried about if there is a large performance hit if I add an index. Do you know in general if indexes slow down inserts significantly, or how I can check how much time it takes?

Comment: You can check by comparing execution time before and after. From my experience I can say that the performance deficit is rather negligible.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, it is better to update totals rather then inserting 10000000 records. For instance, you can have one record per day with the amount of users that day. This will make it much more performant to read out than an aggregate. Even if you want the statistical data for a year, you're only aggregating over 365 records instead of 300 million.

If you must keep them separately, you could try only storing the recent ones as records, and the older ones as cumulative records, cleaning up your database every now and then. If you really need a LOT of statistical data, you should look into other types of databases (data warehouses) that were designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Should I create two tables? One which updates the number of users visiting on a certain day, and another which stores all url's that were visited?

Comment: @eric: I think that might be a better way to go. You can even just have a table with Day (date), url (varchar), usercount (int or bigint) with an index on day and [day/url]. That way you can easily group by day or group by day&url. Put indexes only on things you are using in a "where" clause.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the INSERT DELAYED in another answer.

After midnight, you could store the total nr of visitors in another table like

```
insert into visitor_cache
  select date, count(1)
  from log
  where date < today
  group by date
;
```

Afterwards you could delete the records from your log table.

This way you only have to use the log table for a running total of the current day.

Comment: thanks for the tip (and code!). if I use this cache, do you still recommend I use indexes on the original table? do you think an index just on 'date' is enough?

Comment: If the query performs fast enough when the table only contains log entries for the current day, there is no reason to add an index.